# how to return files in python response from API

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I want to return a csv file that I created in aws lambda function

```
import json
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    myFile = df.to_csv('sample.csv)
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```

This is the default response, how can I return myFile in response

Comment: Why are you not opting to write this to an S3 bucket location and returned a presigned url for the object?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45193012/csv-export-using-api-gateway-and-lambda

Comment: @OluwafemiSule Of course I can do that it's my last resort, but my file is in kb and I want to return the file as an attachment in the api response if possible

Comment: What you're asking is not currently possible with AWS lambda. You need to always return a [response value that is serializable as JSON String](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-handler.html) in your event handler.

Comment: would you like to download this file directly or is your requesting system also one developed by your own? if yes, just send your data as base64 encoded string and just decode it on your client side and save it as CSV... but keep in mind, that the KB from today, could be MB tomorrow, and than you will reach the limit of the responses of API Gateway/Lambda...so if there is the chance, that the csv will grow in future, try to implement the way using S3 (or do manually add gzip your csv before base64 encoding *g*)

Comment: @DanielSeichter Yeah I can do that but you are write about that it could be mb tomorrow. S3 is the best option